# Class / Interface for getting a Reader / InputStream

Tags: java, io, inputstream, abstraction

Simple question: Is there a class or interface that encapulates the getting of a Reader or an InputStream?

What I want is to be able to for example read from a File twice, or a URL twice, and encapulate / abstract the creation of the Reader or InputStream as much as possible

Comment: Reading from a file twice is OK as long as the file isn't gigabytes. Reading from a URL twice is not OK as it implies re-fetching all the data over the network. Maybe you should be saving the data locally and reprocessing it there, or maybe you should be looking harder for a one-pass technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), there is a [`InputSupplier`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/InputSupplier.html) interface, that seems to do what you're looking for.

Guava also has factories that create inputSuppliers, like [`Resources`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Resources.html) or [`Files`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) class - check out the `newInputStreamSupplier` methods in those classes to see how it works.